# Where are .NET User Settings stored IF User = SYSTEM?

Tags: c#, system, settings

I've been working with an updated to update one of my apps and using `Properties.Settings.Default.Upgrade()` and discovered that after my updater restarts my app, it is run under the SYSTEM user instead of the default/logged in user.

This got me wondering, where is the user.config for SYSTEM stored?
I know where the user.config is stored normally (`C:\Documents and Settings\%USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\Application Data\etc...`), but there isn't a folder in `Documents and Settings` for the SYSTEM user. Does anybody know where it is or/how .NET handles this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Local Application Data folder for the SYSTEM account is *usually* located in

```
C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\Local Settings\Application Data\
```

for Windows XP and

```
C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\
```

for later versions.

(I write *usually*, because

- Windows does not need to be installed in `C:\Windows`, and
- the folder names `Local Settings` and `Application Data` are localized in Windows XP, and
- on *64-bit* versions of Windows, the folder for *32-bit* applications is located underneath `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` instead of `System32`.)

Comment: That makes sense, and I see the Microsoft folder in there, but I do not see my app's folder.

Comment: For me path was in `C:\Windows\sysWOW64` end the rest of the path as you specified. Thanks to @Uwe_Keim

Answer (score 4):

Since I don't know the answer, I would do the following to figure out:

1. Install SysInternals [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) ([Direct download](http://live.sysinternals.com/procmon.exe)).
2. Start Process Monitor, set the filter `Path` to your application's name.
3. Start your application.
4. Watch the locations inside Process Monitor.

This helped me often in the past, maybe it could be something for you, too?

Answer (score 0):

```
HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT
```

[is the location](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684190%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) where a non-interactive user gets their profile from when nobody is logged in.

> The registry key **HKEY_CURRENT_USER** is associated with the default user, not the current user. To access another user's profile, impersonate the user, then access **HKEY_CURRENT_USER**.