# Get the location where the config file of a .net Windows service is saved by default

Tags: c#, .net, windows, service

I need to get the location where the config file of a Windows service is saved by default.

I know that for a normal application I can use `ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration`.

The result should be something like:

> {windir}{SysWOW64|System32}\config\systemprofile\AppData{Profile
>   Directory}{Company Name}{App Name}*{Evidence Type}*{Evidence
>   Hash}{Version}\user.config

Which translates to:

> C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\MyComp\MyService.exe_Url_aaddazqww5j4wylfhgidv0ap0mbgc3kv\1.0.0.0\user.config

Thanks

Comment: Is it a service you wrote?

Comment: @GlennFerrie yes

Comment: Isn't it the same as the assembly location, so `string ThisdllDirectory = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);`

Comment: @JordyvanEijk No. In services the location of the config file is located in a different place as shown in my question. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6381859/463464

Comment: The location it's saved by default is adjacent to the executing assembly. If it is elsewhere it would be based on logic of your own design.

Comment: Are you using ClickOnce?

Comment: @GlennFerrie Please see the answer I wrote JordyvanEijk including the provided link

Comment: @Randall Flagg so is your question a dupe of that question? Did the responses from the link fix your issue?

Comment: @GlennFerrie Not using ClickOnce and this is not a dup of the question, as I am not asking where it is located but rather how do I get that location using C#.